# Internet Explorer 10 on Windows 7 does not load embedded fonts

Tags: html, css, .htaccess, internet-explorer, fonts

### Problem details:

I have the problem that Internet Explorer 10 (under Windows 7 - 64 Bit) **does not load fonts embedded with `@font-face` in CSS**. Instead it shows "Arial" or a font like that. I have tested this problem on multiple devices:

- Windows 8 with Internet Explorer 11 (64 Bit)
- Windows 8 with Internet Explorer 10 (64 Bit)
- Windows 7 with Internet Explorer 10 (64 Bit)

But for me this problem never occured. But the strange thing is that **this problem occurs on a customer PC with Internet Explorer 10 and Windows 7** 64 Bit.

The other strange thing is that in the "Network" tab of Internet Explorer shows all resources, but IE will not show any font.
Luckily I have a customer PC to debug this issue. I could not figure out what the problem is yet.

### What I already did to find a solution:

1. I have ensured that the path and `font-family` name is correct. I also ensured that the `@font-face` command is inside the CSS file I have embedded
2. I tried to add the doctype from:

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html> to

   <!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "about:legacy-compat">
   ```
3. I updated the meta tags, e.g.:

   ```
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   ```
4. I also tried to change the order of the font-face `url` commands
5. I removed the `'` from the name of the `font-family`, so from:

   ```
   font-family: 'My font'; to
   font-family: My font;
   ```
6. I also tried to force the correct MIME of the font with a `.htaccess` file like:

   ```
   AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject    .eot
   AddType application/x-font-opentype      .otf
   AddType image/svg+xml                    .svg
   AddType application/x-font-ttf           .ttf
   AddType application/x-woff               .woff
   ```
7. I also installed the website on another server to be sure this is not a server problem
8. I ensured that the chekboxes in Internet Explorer 10 under "Internet options" -> "Accessibility" are not checked

### Technical things:

I am embedding my CSS with:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/base.css">
```

My `@font-face` command looks like:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: MyFont;
    src: url('myPath/MyFont.eot');
    src: url('myPath/MyFont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('myPath/MyFont.woff') format('woff'),
        url('myPath/MyFont.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('myPath/MyFont.svg#myfont') format('svg');
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight : normal;
}
```

// EDIT:
I just want to point out that CSS fonts work generally.  But unfortunately not in on this site.

Comment: All other major browsers do show them correctly?

Comment: @Andi Yes all major browser show them correctly, but not this IE10 on the customer PCs.

Comment: @Alohci Of course, multiple times...

Comment: Could the customer's PC have an unusual security policy applied?

Comment: @Alohci could you tell me a example so that I can look up for it?

Comment: Sorry, not an expert on security policies. I just know that corporate Windows machines, and by extension IE, can be locked down in various ways. It's possible that a rule to block font downloads has been applied, but I don't know if it's possible, or what it would look like. If it is a corporate machine, ask their IT dept.

Comment: Well, that would mean that on all websites `@font-face` is disabled. But that is not the fact. So I do not think this brings the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what solved my problem:
I found out that the customer has a "whitelist" of hosts. Unfortunately my server wasn't on this list. So the customers proxy blocked all font requests from my server.
I don't know the reason for it, but I think the one who configured the proxy thought that a virus or trojan could be downloaded over a font.

Answer (score 1):

Getting @font-face working in Internet Explorer may just be spooky enough. 
as well as you know @font-face already works in Safari 3 via WebKit and is supported in the latest Firefox 3.1 beta. 
With IE, that means around 75% of the world audience could see custom typefaces today if their EULAs allowed it. 
Fortunately, there are good free faces available to us already, as well as some commercial faces that permit embedding. 
so..my onion to use latest version of browser like- chrome, firefox 3.1, safari 3.
Thank you.....

Comment: Sorry but that is not helpful. I am a service provider and can not determine what kind of browser my customers use. Even if I would like to...